# Google Drive SDK REST API - Filter shared files

Tags: google-drive-api

Recently I stared writing some code for an application that uses the [Goggle Drive REST API Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) resource to list all shared files.

But when I add the paramter `q` with `shared = true` the request fails.
Even when using the APIs Explorer's test input form.
Filtering other boolean properties (like `trashed = false`) works.
Sample request:

```
 GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=shared+%3D+true
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from the Fields Table in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#fields), it is possible to search files that are shared with the authorized user by using `sharedWithMe`.

Sample request:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=sharedWithMe+%3D+true`